# Vim can't be started inside Windows Subsystem(WSL) when using Git for Windows executable

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, git-for-windows

after having performance Issues with default git in bash for windows subsystem(wsl) I switched to git provided for Windows(Added it to my path)

Now that I am using git for windows inside the WSL Subsystem bash it is no longer starting vim as my Editor.

This is the Error I get:

```
Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
```

How can I tell git for windows to start vim without error when I am in the bash for windows shell?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I’m having exactly the same issue where I switched to using Windows git inside WSL because it is significantly faster when working with a large repo on /mnt/ shares. For now I have resorted to setting my core.editor to Windows gvim, which works - it launches a new instance and allows me to keep the same muscle memory of :wq - but I’d love to find a way of having console vim work correctly.